# Get File created date for file in a directory C#

Tags: ssis

I have a folder that has files moved to it from another directory. I need to report the date when the file was created in the folder Using c# in script task in SSIS, but when I use `System.IO.fileInfo.CreationTime` I get the file modification date instead.

see attached image[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CreationTime` property of the `FileInfo` class to find when the file was created.  The example below details this further.  Also note that this uses `DateTime.Today` to only look at dates, as this defaults to midnight.  If you need to check for the time as well use `Datetime.Now`.

```
            DirectoryInfo ParentFolder = new DirectoryInfo("YourFolderPath");

            var allFiles = ParentFolder.EnumerateFiles("*.*");

            foreach (FileInfo fi in ParentFolder.GetFiles())
            {
                //this examples checks for files created seven or more days ago
                if (fi.CreationTime <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7))
                {                   
                   //do necessary work here     
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,whatt i need is to isert the information related file into sql table i pass modified date by using system.io.creationtime now i need to insert created date (see picture attached) i tried to use lastwrite time but it also doesn't give me the write date.